# How to set language of paypal page when using Adaptive Payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I've searched in the documentation of `PayRequest` message and there is no option\property there to set the paypal page default language .

currently the page is shown in english and I want it to be displayed in hebrew.

I did try to add this line in my form :

```
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="he_IL">
```

though it seems that this doesn't work when using Adaptive payment .

The `RequestEnvelope` has only errorLanguage property which is not what I`m looking for ( and its only option is en_US)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AP doesn't have an absolute variable for this like some of the other Classic APIs, however as a workaround, you could add the country code to the redirect URL for some languages.  For example, the below URL will display in German due to adding the /de/.

https://www.paypal.com/de/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=AP-xxxxxxxx

Keep in mind that not all countries will display the corresponding language.  Another thing to keep in mind is that other factors could override this as well such as default browser language, buyer location, and browser cookie.

Comment: I`ve tried : https://www.paypal.com/il/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=AP-xxxxxxxx AND https://www.paypal.com/isr/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=AP-xxxxxxxx . They both give me the page in english, instead of hebrew - the language of israel people. ( in contrary to /de/ which does present the language in german ) am i doing something wrong ? if no, is there any other way around this ? `il` should work as this page :  https://www.paypal.com/il is presented with hebrew .

Comment: As I stated, not all countries/languages are supported with this particular method. Without having a specific variable for this in AP, this would be the only way to encourage a specific language on checkout. Also, there are other browser specific things that influence the language as well as paypal.com/il displays in English when I visit it.

Comment: maybe because you didnt clear your cookies, anyway, this does works for me : https://www.paypal.com/il/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=AP-xxxxxxxx Thanks alot !

Answer (score 1):

add `&country.x=` and the RFC 3066 of the country

Comment: This doesnt work : https://www.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/expresscheckoutincontextremembermeflow?execution=e3s2&country.x=he_IL neither with country.x=he OR with local.x=he_IL any idea why?

Comment: Hi @jony89 I'm from Portugal and I was using local.x=PT with no success. I changed to local.x=BR and it worked for Brazilian Portuguese.

Comment: yes this works for me also, though https://www.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/expresscheckoutincontextremembermeflow?execution=e3s2&country.x=il doesnt work ( although there is an option to change to hebrew language manually if i want) :S

Comment: Should local.x be locale.x (note the extra e at the end)?